# Got unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with laravel dusk in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to implement browser testing with Laravel Dusk in docker environment.
But when I  run command `php artisan dusk` to testing (in my php container) it display this error for all my tests case:

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.45)

/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:139
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:372
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:585
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/WebDriverNavigation.php:41
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:153
/var/www/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:19
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:69
/var/www/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21
```

Here is my configuration:

I add `selenium` container to docker-compose file by this [introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#laravel-dusk)

- `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

networks:
    laravel:

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/php/Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        extra_hosts: 
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
        depends_on:
            - selenium
    selenium:
        container_name: selenium
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - './selenium:/selenium'
        networks:
            - laravel
```

I have follow introduction in laravel documentation page [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#using-other-browsers) to change `APP_URL` config to `http://selenium:4444/wd/hub`

- `DuskTestCase.php`

```php
    public static function prepare()
    {
        if (! static::runningInSail()) {
            static::startChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
            return $items->merge([
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless'
            ]);
        })->all());

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', // change here
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
```

Then when I run testing in `php` container it show error above.

#### UPDATE

I've checked my `selenium` logs and it shows this error whenever I run command `php artisan dusk`

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 58188

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

[1639062447.255][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

I wonder if this erro come from my configuration or my implement steps. So, this is detail of steps I used to implement testing:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exe php bash
// php container
php artisan config:clear
php artisan dusk
```

Hope it help to figure out solution

Comment: Both containers are on the same network so try `127.0.0.1:4444` as the selenium host

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @apokryfos I've tried to change in `RemoteWebDriver::create()` param to `http://127.0.0.1:4444`. But it shows error `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4444: Connection refused` for each test case

Comment: @QuentinCaffeino I just have checked logs and updated to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fixed this issues. I've config wrong `APP_URL` in `.env.dusk.local`.
It should have been `APP_URL=http://nginx` (with `nginx` is container containing nginx server)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing shm_size on your selenium instance, it probably doesn't work. Here's the example docker-compose file: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

Note that it should be >=2gb.

Comment: It doesn't work, it shows the same message